# button command not excuting the function

Tags: python, function, button, tkinter

I made a Complement angles calculator that calculates if two angles are Complement or equal 90 and I also worked on the GUI with tkinter, there is a button in it that is supposed to excute a function but it doesn't, I've been working so much on it but i couldn't understand what's wrong with it.

Tkinter button's commands like this one below must execute a function

```
process = Button(root, text="click!", command=function).pack()
```

but in my codes, it doesn't work and I don't know why. PLEASE someone help me!!!
here is my codes:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Complement angles calculator")
root.geometry("400x400+0+0")

heading_app = Label(root, text="Complement angles calculator", font=("arial", 20), fg="steelblue").pack()
angle1 = Label(root, text="First angle : ", font=("arial", 20), fg="black").place(x=10, y=80)

fir_angle = IntVar()
angle1_box = Entry(root, width=15, textvariable=fir_angle, bg="#ffffff").place(x=185, y=92)


angle2 = Label(root, text="Second angle : ", font=("arial", 20), fg="black").place(x=10, y=120)

sec_angle = IntVar()
angle2_box = Entry(root, width=15, textvariable=sec_angle, bg="#ffffff").place(x=220, y=132)

angles = fir_angle.get() + sec_angle.get()

def function():
    if angles == 90:
        text = Label(root, text="Resault :", font=("arial", 15)).place(x=155, y=250)
        text = Label(root, text="These are 90° Complement angles", font=("arial", 15)).place(x=50, y=300)

    if angles == 180:
        text = Label(root, text="Resault :", font=("arial", 15)).place(x=155, y=250)
        text = Label(root, text="These are 180° Complement angles", font=("arial", 15)).place(x=50, y=300)

    if angles == 360:
        text = Label(root, text="Resault :", font=("arial", 15)).place(x=155, y=250)
        text = Label(root, text="These are 360° Complement angles", font=("arial", 15)).place(x=50, y=300)

    if angles != 90 or angles != 180 or angles != 360:
        text = Label(root, text="Resault :", font=("arial", 15)).place(x=155, y=250)
        text = Label(root, text="These are NOT Complement angles", font=("arial", 15)).place(x=40, y=300)
function()

process = Button(root, text="Are these Complement angles ?", font=("arial", 15), command=function).place(x=50, y=175)

root.mainloop()
```

Why doesn't it execute the function() ?
I appreciate that you help me!

Comment: When I run your code the function executes. Why do you think it doesn't? Are you _sure_ your function isn't executing? Or is it executing and just not doing what you expect it to do?

Comment: The result of `function()` is determined entirely by `angles`, which was calculated *once* during the startup of your program.  Calling it again will therefore not change anything on screen.  You need to move that calculation into the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a few things to correct.

First lets do `import tkinter as tk` instead of using `*` This way we do not overwrite other imports.

Next lets clean up your variables. We do not need to name everything. Just the stuff we are going to call later.

Next we need to move `angles = fir_angle.get() + sec_angle.get()` into your function so we can get the values at the time they are needed.

Next we need to rename your function as "function" is the name of the internal method and this will cause issues.

Next lets fix your if statements. We can simply check a list of values and use `format()` for the text.

Lets add some error handling with try/except.

You will notice I am using `config()` to update the labels instead of trying to place labels on top of each other.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Complement angles calculator')
root.geometry('400x400+0+0')
fir_angle = tk.IntVar()
sec_angle = tk.IntVar()
tk.Label(root, text='Complement angles calculator', font=('arial', 20), fg='steelblue').pack()
tk.Label(root, text='First angle : ', font=('arial', 20), fg='black').place(x=10, y=80)
tk.Entry(root, width=15, textvariable=fir_angle, bg='#ffffff').place(x=185, y=92)
tk.Label(root, text='Second angle : ', font=('arial', 20), fg='black').place(x=10, y=120)
tk.Entry(root, width=15, textvariable=sec_angle, bg='#ffffff').place(x=220, y=132)
lbl1 = tk.Label(root, font=('arial', 15))
lbl1.place(x=155, y=250)
lbl2 = tk.Label(root, font=('arial', 15))
lbl2.place(x=50, y=300)


def func():  # do not call functions 'function' its a built in method
    try:
        angles = fir_angle.get() + sec_angle.get()
        lbl1.config(text='Resault :')
        if angles in [90, 180, 360]:
            lbl2.config(text='These are {}° Complement angles'.format(angles))
        else:
            lbl2.config(text='These are &$#@ Complement angles')
    except:
        lbl1.config(text='Error :')
        lbl2.config(text='Invalid values in entry fields')


tk.Button(root, text='Are these Complement angles ?', font=('arial', 15), command=func).place(x=50, y=175)
root.mainloop()
```

I would also recomend you use `grid()` or `pack()` instead of `place()` for widgets as it is much easier to maintain your code as it grows.

Here is an example using `grid()`:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Complement angles calculator')
root.geometry('400x300+0+0')
fir_angle = tk.IntVar()
sec_angle = tk.IntVar()
tk.Label(root, text='Complement angles calculator',
         font=('arial', 20), fg='steelblue').grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='w')
tk.Label(root, text='First angle: ', font=('arial', 20), fg='black').grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='e')
tk.Entry(root, width=15, textvariable=fir_angle, bg='#ffffff').grid(row=1, column=1)
tk.Label(root, text='Second angle: ', font=('arial', 20), fg='black').grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='e')
tk.Entry(root, width=15, textvariable=sec_angle, bg='#ffffff').grid(row=2, column=1)
lbl1 = tk.Label(root, font=('arial', 15))
lbl1.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=(20, 0))
lbl2 = tk.Label(root, font=('arial', 15))
lbl2.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2)


def func():  # do not call functions 'function' its a built in method
    try:
        angles = fir_angle.get() + sec_angle.get()
        lbl1.config(text='Resault :')
        if angles in [90, 180, 360]:
            lbl2.config(text='These are {}° Complement angles'.format(angles))
        else:
            lbl2.config(text='These are &$#@ Complement angles')
    except:
        lbl1.config(text='Error :')
        lbl2.config(text='Invalid values in entry fields')


tk.Button(root, text='Are these Complement angles ?', font=('arial', 15),
          command=func).grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)
root.mainloop()
```

Results: -- Not sure why this image is so large. The actual image is small.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your function *is* executing.

I suspect the problem is that you're expecting `angles` to change, but it won't. You set it to a value once, and then don't ever change it.

Instead, you need to defer calling the `get()` methods until the function is called.

```
def function():
    angles = fir_angle.get() + sec_angle.get()
    ...
```

You also have a logic problem, because `angles != 90 or angles != 180 or angles != 360` will always be true, since `angles` can't be three values at once. At least two of those three parts of the statement will always be true.

For example, if angles is 90 (ie: `angles != 90` is `False`), `angles != 180` will be `True`, and `angles != 360` will also be `True`, making the statement `if False or True or True`, which is the same as `if (False is True) or (True is True) or (True is True)`.

Answer (score -2):

Try adding this line After button widget:

process.pack()

Comment: The OP is already using Place. This will not fix the issue with the function.